# ZF2 - Collection of input[email]

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

This question may look really simple but I can't find any answer on the web neither in the ZF2 "documentation".

I am simply trying to create a collection of inputs of type "email" and validates it but I don't find the way to do so properly using zend-form.

(The form may be able to add or remove some of these email elements)

The HTML should look like this :

```
<form>
    <input name="additionalEmails[]" type="email" />
    <input name="additionalEmails[]" type="email" />
    <input name="additionalEmails[]" type="email" />
</form>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend Framework has 'Form Collections' that help you to achieve this.

You can read more about this in the Zend Framework documentation.
https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html

In the documentation, they use the Collection type to create a collection of fieldsets, but you can use the same code to make a collection of basic elements (like your e-mail field).

The `allow_add` flag will enable adding and deleting items. If you wish to do this dynamically, you might need to write some javascript, but Zend Form gives you a nice HTML template you can use. This is also described in the documentation here:
https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html#adding-new-elements-dynamically

Comment: Thx. I didn't realized that we can add an element instead of a whole fiedset. It works perfectly fine.